# How to untar a file skipping the beginning of the directory structure?

Tags: linux, tar, archive

I created tar archives with an absolute path to save the files.

```
/home/mydir/dir1/dir2/dir3/file1.dat
/home/mydir/dir1/dir2/dir3/file2.dat
/home/mydir/dir1/dir2/dir3/file3.dat
```

I would like to untar these archives skipping the leading part of the path, `/home/mydir/dir1`. My files should be restored in any directory with this structure:

```
dir2/dir3/file1.dat
dir2/dir3/file2.dat
dir2/dir3/file3.dat
```

How can I do this with the tar command, or another way?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using GNU tar, then there is an option to remove some
leading path members when extracting:

```
 `--strip-components=number'

    Strip given number of leading components from file names before extraction.

For example, suppose you have archived whole `/usr' hierarchy to a
tar archive named `usr.tar'. Among other files, this archive
contains `usr/include/stdlib.h', which you wish to extract to the
current working directory. To do so, you type:

$ tar -xf usr.tar --strip=2 usr/include/stdlib.h
```

(From the [GNU tar documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_52.html#transform).)

In your case, `--strip=3` should apply.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU tar (found on non-embedded Linux and Cygwin), you can apply a regular expression replacement to the paths when adding members to an archive or when extracting them with the [`--transform` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#show_002dtransformed_002dnames).

```
tar -xf foo.tar --transform='s!^/home/mydir/dir1/!!'
```

With [*BSD tar](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=1) (including on OSX), there's a similar option called `-s`.

```
tar -xf foo.tar -s '!^/home/mydir/dir1/!!'
```

POSIX has the [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html) command with the same option as BSD tar.

```
pax -r <foo.tar -s '!^/home/mydir/dir1/!!'
```